# To what is the judge in the Lina E. trial referring to by "deplorable deficiencies in recent trials of far-right extremists"?

Tags: germany, reference-request

[It is in the news](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-65801804) that there have been protests after the sentencing of Lina E for attacks on neo-Nazis. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_Lina_E.#Arrest_and_trial) quoting [this German language news article](https://www.fr.de/politik/antifa-news-lina-e-prozess-urteil-verkuendung-demo-leipzig-dresden-kassel-linksextremismus-zr-92312816.html) says:

> Hans Schlüter-Staats, the Higher Regional Court of Dresden judge overseeing the trial, stated that "opposing right-wing extremists is a respectable motive" and that there had been "deplorable" deficiencies in recent trials of far-right extremists

To what cases is the judge referring to here?

Comment: German trials have a *verbal* and a *written* explanation of the verdict. Until the written one gets published, which will take weeks or months, we would have to guess what the judge means. A better question would be which high-profile failures there were in the prosecution of right-wing extremists in Dresden/Saxony/Eastern Germany/Germany.

Comment: Strange: neither the quoted article ([2023-06-02 05:57: Prozess gegen Lina E.: Stadt Leipzig verbietet Solidaritäts-Demonstration](https://web.archive.org/web/20230602053810/https://www.fr.de/politik/news-lina-e-prozess-urteil-verkuendung-demo-leipzig-dresden-kassel-linksextremismus-antifa-zr-92312816.html) from the english version of Wikipedea nor the german Wikipedia version ([Dresdner Linksextremismusprozess – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresdner_Linksextremismusprozess) uses the quote given in the english version.

Comment: In the article, the name 'Hans Schlueter-Staats' is used once: *The arrest warrant against them will be suspended against conditions, said **Hans Schlueter-Staats**, presiding judge of the State Protection Chamber at the Dresden Higher Regional Court, on Wednesday evening at the end of the verdict.  She only has to serve the remainder of the sentence if the verdict becomes final.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To what cases is the judge referring to here?

None: neither the quoted article ([2023-06-02 05:57: Prozess gegen Lina E.: Stadt Leipzig verbietet Solidaritäts-Demonstration](https://web.archive.org/web/20230602053810/https://www.fr.de/politik/news-lina-e-prozess-urteil-verkuendung-demo-leipzig-dresden-kassel-linksextremismus-antifa-zr-92312816.html)) given in the [english version of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_of_Lina_E.#Arrest_and_trial) nor the german Wikipedia version ([Dresdner Linksextremismusprozess – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dresdner_Linksextremismusprozess) uses the quote given in the english version.

In the article itself, the name 'Hans Schlueter-Staats' is used only once:

> The arrest warrant against them will be suspended against conditions, said **Hans Schlueter-Staats**, presiding judge of the State Protection Chamber at the Dresden Higher Regional Court, on Wednesday evening at the end of the verdict. She only has to serve the remainder of the sentence if the verdict becomes final.

Assume that, for whatever reason, someone added a fabricated quote, in the Wikipedia page, that is **not** contained in the given source hoping that nobody would notice (either because the reader can't read German or simply wouldn't look).

It would be **very strange** for a judge whos primary duty, in a civil law system, is to *read the law as written*, to give a personal opinion about previous rulings (which was the reason I looked: to read the exact German text).

Whoever fabricated that quote was obviously unaware of this **or** didn't care hoping that others would simply assume it to be correct due the given source of a newspaper that has a reputation as being a reliable source.